# optimise Google Apps script

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Could anyone please help me optimise this Google Sheets script?

It's painfully slow. It barely makes 300 copies in 24 hours (I need the Drive API to make the copies as "view only users can't copy/print/download")

```
function addCopies() {
  var count = 10;
  var input = DriveApp.getFileById('1GQI5m0g5XsCWi1dOTBWFs3VJkzW7e8N__09C3-2BEGI')
  var results = DriveApp.getFileById('1gkOCTPJuqTQnNNlaE3jD2Hq2COU-lO02PmlO_xMepx0')

  var indexSH = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1o6ZfweVylhnDXoVc9u_R8afKdVfXYgtdqtj_lSCdFEk').getSheetByName('Index')

  for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
  {
    //make copies of both files (input & results)
    var inputCopy = input.makeCopy(input.getName(), DriveApp.getFolderById('0B0go-fsdFA3ISG0xNGlhTDZoM0U'))
    inputCopy.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT)
    var inputID = inputCopy.getId()
    //make results to be restricted using API
    var resultsCopy = results.makeCopy(results.getName(), DriveApp.getFolderById('0B0go-fsdFA3ISG0xNGlhTDZoM0U'))
    resultsCopy.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW)
    var resultsID = resultsCopy.getId()
    var apiFile = DriveAPI.Files.get(resultsID)
    apiFile.labels.restricted = true    
    DriveAPI.Files.update(apiFile, resultsID)

    //save IDs of both files to an index for later re-use
    var lastRow = indexSH.getRange(1,1).getValue()
    var addRng = indexSH.getRange(lastRow+1, 1,1,3)
    addRng.setValues([['free',inputID,resultsID]])

  }
}
```

Edit: techydesigner said "we don't optimise code on SO" . So please let me rephrase : am I using the wrong Drive services ? Is there a method to make those copies faster ?